# Как передать параметры в main

Tags: java, main

Дана задача - Программа должна запускаться с параметрами. Первый параметр - начальная папка. Второй параметр - расширение файлов, которые нужно искать.Как передать параметры в идее , что нужно написать в строчке programm arguments? edit configurations

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SearchFiles searcher = new SearchFiles(x -> x.endsWith(args[1]));
        String temp = args[0];
        Path path = Paths.get(temp);
        Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(args[0]), searcher);
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37103762/13941944

Comment: Спасибо помогло решить задачу